# Cellvaluechanged doesn't fire after bind datasource to radgrid?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, telerik, radgrid

Have Radgrid which have Cellvaluechanged Event
after bind list as grid datasource The Cellvaluechanged  doesn't fire ?

```
rgv_AlternativItem.DataSource = S.ListAlternatives;
rgv_AlternativItem.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CellValueChanged should not fire when you rebind the grid. To detect this moment, you can use the **DataBindingComplete** event.